# Kestrel behind HAProxy, many uncaught exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, haproxy, kestrel-http-server

I'm seeing many exception logs in a Kestrel server (ASP.NET Core 3.1) behind HAProxy.
I'm trying to understand if this is configuration related that should be improved or if there's an issue that should be looked into:

```
    00:19:40.033 [th-282] [Debug] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel] Connection id "0HMH80KISBCOF" started. 
00:19:41.002 [th-137] [Debug] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets] Connection id "0HMH80KISBCOF" reset. 
00:19:41.019 [th-144] [Error] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel] Uncaught exception from the OnConnectionAsync method of an IConnectionAdapter. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.<GetResult>g__ThrowSocketException|7_0(SocketError e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.<ProcessReceives>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.<DoReceive>d__23.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Adapter.Internal.RawStream.<ReadAsyncInternal>d__22.MoveNext()
00:19:41.035 [th-137] [Debug] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets] Connection id "0HMH80KISBCOF" sending FIN because: "The Socket transport's send loop completed gracefully." 
00:19:41.050 [th-179] [Debug] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel] Connection id "0HMH80KISBCOF" disconnecting. 
00:19:41.066 [th-144] [Debug] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel] Connection id "0HMH80KISBCOF" stopped.
```

as well as:

```
16:07:23.380 [th-191] [Debug] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel] Connection id "0HMH80KISBCTS" completed keep alive response. 
16:07:24.044 [th-191] [Debug] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets] Connection id "0HMH80KISBCTS" reset. 
16:07:24.044 [th-505] [Debug] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets] Connection id "0HMH80KISBCTS" sending FIN because: "The client closed the connection." 
16:07:24.044 [th-505] [Debug] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel] Connection id "0HMH80KISBCTS" disconnecting. 
16:07:24.044 [th-505] [Info] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel] Connection id "0HMH80KISBCTS" request processing ended abnormally. System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.<GetResult>g__ThrowSocketException|7_0(SocketError e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.<ProcessReceives>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.<DoReceive>d__23.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Adapter.Internal.RawStream.<ReadAsyncInternal>d__22.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Adapter.Internal.RawStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrimPromise`1.Complete(TInstance thisRef, Func`3 endMethod, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Adapter.Internal.AdaptedPipeline.<ReadInputAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.<ProcessRequests>d__185`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.<ProcessRequestsAsync>d__184`1.MoveNext()
16:07:24.044 [th-505] [Debug] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel] Connection id "0HMH80KISBCTS" stopped.
```

The config on the HAProxy side is simply:

```
listen c-https
   bind 1.2.3.4:443
   mode tcp
   option tcplog
   server server1 5.6.7.8:443
   server server2 5.6.7.9:443
```

and Kestrel is using TLS:

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "HttpsInlineCertStore": {
        "Url": "https://+",
        "Certificate": {
          "Subject": "*.mydomain.com",
          "Store": "My",
          "Location": "LocalMachine",
          "AllowInvalid": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Let HAProxy handle https and send the request to kestrel as http.  You’ll also need to switch the haproxy back to http mode. 
I’ve never been able to get haproxy to run in https pass through .